# How to display the video in separate window using spyder

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I'm trying to import a Youtube video using the below code:

```
from IPython.display import YouTubeVideo

YouTubeVideo("KsdsCdzsito" , width=800 , height=700)
```

And want to display the GUI output in a separate window. So can anyone suggest me a method to display in a new window?

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is not possible at the moment (February 2019), sorry.

*Note*: We have some plans to allow users view web content generated in our consoles in a dedicated panel, but there's nothing concrete yet.